# Proper way to avoid Implicit Conversion warning when setting an NSCell to a NSUinteger value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, type-conversion

I am converting some old Cocoa code to the current Cocoa system.

I have a window that has some cells on it. They are NSCell subclasses.

I want to set the value of a cell to the `length` of an `NSRange` structure. So my code looks like this:

```
[numPagesCell setIntValue:range.length];
```

The problem I am getting is that `NSRange.length` is an `NSUinteger` and the `setIntValue:` method takes an `unsigned long`. I'd rather not do a cast here, as this is something I do a lot. What's the appropriate way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use setIntegerValue: instead of setIntValue: